# lua overload table __tostring function

Tags: printing, lua

I have a simple problem:  I would like to cause the `print` function in lua to print the contents of a table, rather than just the word "table" and a memory address.  For example:

```
> tab = {}
> tab[1]="hello"
> tab[2]="there"
> 
> print(tab)
table: 0x158ab10
--should be 
1   hello
2   there
```

I am aware that I can get this effect by executing something like:

```
for i,v in pairs(tab) do print(i,v) end
```

but I would like it to happen simply when I execute `print(tab)` rather than having to write out a loop every time.  can this be done?

Comment: FYI: `print` is primarily intended for debugging purposes. If you need to do serious work with printing data, you want to use the proper IO routines.

Comment: @NicolBolas care to elaborate on "proper IO routines"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to set __tostring() on every table you created. An easier way would be to use a pretty printing technique.

See this link: http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by overriding the global `tostring()` function. This is what `print()` calls on its arguments.

If you do not want to do any coding, try out the [Microlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Microlight) library by Steve Donovan. You can use it as follows:

```
tostring = require "ml".tstring
tab = {"abc", 3.14, print, key="value", otherkey={1, 2, 3}}
print(tab) --> {"abc",3.14,function: 0x7f5a40,key="value",otherkey={1,2,3}}
```